# Is There a Way to Get Chatter Notifications?

Tags: chatter, notification, connect-api, chatter-rest-api

If you @mention or send a message to a Chatter user, you get a notification in Salesforce1. This appears immediately so it's a safe bet that push notifications are being used to dispatch them. However if I then log into Salesforce1 via `/one/one.app`, I can still see those same notifications in the same state (i.e. read/unread).

Is there a way I can get this list of notifications, be it via the API or through Apex? I don't need them real-time like push notifications, but just being able to poll for them.

Comment: I assume you are after an official API rather than a grey area that would give you the same data? I'm sure with enough motivation the underlying data source that Salesforce1 is using could be extracted.

Comment: Yeah ideally. I suspect that Salesforce1 is using push notifications and that it's actually hooked up to that in the internals of Chatter... would be good to know though!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this yet, but it's something that we want to provide. I encourage you to submit an idea on the IdeaExchange for working with in-app notifications through the API and Apex.

Comment: IdeaExchange is where good ideas go to die ;) I'll give it a crack but IMHO IdeaExchange has never fulfilled it's destiny and become what it should be.

Comment: Agreed, IdeaExchange never delivers developer ideas, never gets enough votes. I thought Parker Harris said everything in Salesforce is API first and 10x the APIs at last dreamforce?  It is in Salesforce1 so it must have an API and data behind it, he said Salesforce1 was only built on APIs. Cant be that hard to open it up ;)

Comment: IdeaExchange link... https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000wkNCAAY

Comment: Any changes on this in the past 4 years?

Comment: @zaitsman Not that I'm aware of, if you find anything please do post an answer here though! :)